# socket.io not working inside zmq function

Tags: zeromq, socket.io

i am putting socketio inside zmq but its not working below is the code
not sure what i am doing wrong

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(2939);
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('sub');

console.log("Connecting to Currency Stream....");

socket.subscribe("");

    socket.on('message', function (data){
    //console.log(data.toString());
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log("In socket.io");
        console.log(data.toString());
        socket.emit("live_rates",
              {date: data[0], time: data[1], 
                    open: data[2], high: data[3], 
                        low: data[4], close: data[5]});
        socket.emit("news", {hello: 'world'});
        console.log("emitted");
    }); 
});  

    socket.connect('tcp://localhost:3191');
```

code inside io.socket.on is not running, handshake is successful as i can see in the log window. when i am putting the code inside zmq (uncomment //console.log(data.toString()); )
it's showing the data.

what i am really doing here is getting the data from zmq server on a zmq tcp port 3191 and forward it to socket.io http port 2939, then getting the data on browser by connecting to port 2939 using an html page. i do not wish to use zmq on client side as socket.io is much robust for that play.

also a separate socket.io connection ie io.sockets.on is working but inside a zmq socket it fails!

any one

zishan

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using io.sockets.emit rather than socket.emit.
io.socket.on is now placed outside of zmq.

i suspect socketio callback is now responding if using socket.emit when using inside zmq function.

got a clue from this blog post
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/socket_io/Vi0uWeHsj_0/JEOcXAc-pn8J